# IStreamBufferMediaSeeking setPosition doesn't seem to render

Tags: c#, directshow

I have created two DirectShow graphs.  One captures from a Hauppauge HD-PVR and stores it in a StreamBufferSink.  The second one uses a `StreamBufferSource`, sends the output to an MPEG-2 Demultiplexer, sending the video to the ArcSoft Video Decoder and on to a Video Mixing Renderer 9 set up in windowless mode.

This all works fine for previewing the data.  When I use the `IStreamBufferMediaSeeking.SetPositions` method (getting the interface from the `StreamBufferSource`) to change the playback position, if I set it anywhere but at the beginning of the stream, the video freezes and stops updating.  Calling `GetCurrentPosition` on `IStreamBufferMediaSeeking` shows the position is moving on the stream, but the video just doesn't follow along.

I am using C# and DirectShowLib-2005 for programming things.

Any ideas on what is wrong or how to figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I have discovered is the StreamBufferSink/StreamBufferSource only understand MPEG-2 or DV video.  H.264 is not supported so it doesn't know how to seek within the stream and thus I cannot use this component for what I want to do unless I transcode my stream to MPEG-2 which defeats the purpose for having an H.264 stream in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Further information: This actually will work under Windows 7 with the updates to the Streaming Buffer Engine. To get rewind, I had to demux the stream and add the MPEG-2 Video Stream Analyzer filter before putting the data into the Stream Buffer Sink.